# C# soap request

Tags: c#, soap

I have done a request SOAP with SOAPUI and all works fine. The request is equal to the xmlString with Basic Authentication type.

I need to do this request into a c# solution but my code doesn't work:

```
string xmlString = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:soap=""http://soap.service.tracking.sda.it/"">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <soap:doIt>
                         <arg0>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <codCliente>00000000001</codCliente>
                            <!--1 to 10 repetitions:-->
                            <datiSpedizione>
                               <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
                               <!--Optional:-->
                               <idLdv>000001</idLdv>
                               <!--Optional:-->
                               <ultimoStato>N</ultimoStato>
                            </datiSpedizione>
                            <descrizioneStatus>E</descrizioneStatus>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <postazione>00001</postazione>
                            <tipologiaCliente>SDA</tipologiaCliente>
                         </arg0>
                      </soap:doIt>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>";
HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest("https://ws.sda.it/TRACKING","user","pass");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 32000;
request.Timeout = 32000;
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xmlString);
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
}
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And this is the createWebRequestMethod:

```
public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string user, string pass)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", "TRACKING");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }
```

When i try to use this code i go into an exception of "Null reference" in the request.GetResponse()

Comment: Thank you for your suggest Ed. 
I just thought it might be useful to see that on SOAPUI the request work fine and I cut the main part with the authentication type. I apologize if I'm wrong

Comment: Have you tried generating the SOAP service reference using Visual Studio? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/step-2-adding-a-web-reference

Comment: I have replaced the image with some information. The xml text is equal to the string xmlString in the code